# ElasticSearch Exact search with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am having some issues with using customized mappings for ElasticSearch with Javascript. Specifically, I am trying to have one index, with one type of document, in which 2 fields shouldn't be indexed (I will need an exact search later on).

My mapping is as follows:

```
client.indices.putMapping({
  index: 'history',
  include_type_name: true,
  type: 'pageDataToUser',
    body: {
      properties: {
        userId: {
          type: 'keyword',
          index: false
        },
        url: {
          type: 'keyword',
          index: false
        },
        pageTitle: {
          type: 'text'
        },
        pageText: {
          type: 'text'
        },
        log: {
          type: 'text'
        }

      }
    },

}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err.stack || err);
});
```

I am trying to create the index as follows:

```
client.indices.create({
  index: 'history'
}, (err, resp, status) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log('create', resp)
  }
})
```

I am getting the following error:
Error: [index_not_found_exception] no such index [history], with { resource.type="index_or_alias" & resource.id="history" & index_uuid="*na*" & index="history" }

I've looked everywhere in the documentation, but unfortunately am unable to understand what is wrong. I am using "elasticsearch": "^16.6.0".

Thanks

Comment: Version 16.6.0? This is not the version of elasticsearch itself. What kind of lib is this?

Comment: This was the version of the npm package (elasticsearch), with an ES 6.8. In the meantime I've upgraded my ES version - I am using ElasticSearch 7.5.2. Also, I have found the solution to my question - I needed to set some custom mappings with type keyword, and query based on term. Thanks anyway.